# How to grow file system to fill EFI system partition

Tags: partitioning

I wanted to increase the EFI system partition so I added 100 MB of unallocated space to it on gparted but after I executed the order it now gives a warning sign saying "101.00 MiB of unallocated space within the partition.To grow the file system to fill the partition,select the partition and choose the menu item: Partition>Check." So I clicked check but it just says error and doesn't repair it

Comment: What is the reason for increasing the EFI partition?

Comment: Well it was getting kinda full

Comment: You don't modify the partitions on a running Linux system. Boot from a Live USB and then use GParted to resize the partitions.

Comment: Ok thank you very much